# What is the fastest animation on the iPad

Tags: ipad

What is the fastest animation on the iPad? There are multiple flipping types, what is the fastest one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean by fastest. If you want a speedier animation, you can always change the duration with

```
[UIView setAnimationDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration];
```

If you're talking about performance, on the other hand - It's really not an issue if you're managing your network calls etc. on another thread. The UI updating always happens on the primary thread, so all you have to do is detach your network calls and heavy processing.

If the heavy processing is  *too heavy* for multithreading to save you, then you can always look at Core Animation. It's much lower level, and faster.

Answer (score 1):

You are limited by the hardware display refresh to a maximum of 60 fps.

You can do any of OpenGL, CG drawing in a drawRect, manual CALayer animation frame swaps, or use Core Animation at that frame rate if you are very very careful about how much you do on the UI thread during each frame time.